# Google Tag Manager: cannot see Data Layer property value in tag

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, google-datalayer

I added to all my pages the following:

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager Data Layer -->
<script>
dataLayer=[{'author': 'abc'}]
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager Data Layer -->
```

I set up in Google Tag Manger the following Variable:

[image: Data Layer Variable]

so that I get to this situation:

[image]

Then I set my Universal Analytics tag as follows:

[image]

The tag is set up in order to be fired at every page view. When I reload the page I see that my Data Layer contains the "author":

[image]

But if I check the tag in Google Tag Assistant I don't see the expected field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Author' is not a valid Google Analytics field. I don't know offhand all the valid fields, but they include 'page', 'cookiedomain', 'allowLinker' -  'author' certainly isn't one of them. You might want to try defining a custom dimension in your property settings and setting the value of that with the author.